# How to split a batch for a multiple head network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train a multiple head network with a shared backbone and two different datasets. One network head is for classification and the other is for segmentation. Similarly, one dataset is for classification and one is for segmentation. The datasets are concatenated and a single dataloader is used with shuffle=True. Each batch fed to the model can therefore be a mixture of the two datasets, identifiable by parameter "m" added as another dimension of the batch. The following is the pseudo-code for the forward method:

```
x = self.backbone(x)
x_1 = self.segmentation_head(x[torch.where(m == 0)]) 
x_2 = self.classification_head(x[torch.where(m == 1)])
return x_1 , x_2
```

The segmentation task and classification task converges well and gives good results only when the dataloader takes either only from the segmentation dataset or only from the classification dataset, but not in this mixed implementation. Therefore I think the issue is related to the back-propagation calculation. Is the way I am splitting the batch valid?

Comment: Hello Adam and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is overly broad and will probably need some more focus in order to get an answer on this site.

Comment: The question is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

The way I implemented the solution is correct. There was an error in another part of the code that led me to believe otherwise.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).